# Why does DataContext class create a new database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Guys I am a new bee to asp .net mvc 3.

In the MS Visual Web Developer Express 2010, I created a new project using Visual C# / Web / ASP .net MVC 3 Web App using a form authentication template. I deleted all the controller and view files and added my own. I added a new `sample.mdf` database in the `App_Data` folder and changed the connection string accordingly and created country model.

But when I create CRUD controller for the country model it asks me for the `DataContext` class. It does not accept empty and I have to mention `DataContext` class. And when I create a `DataContext` class, it creates a new database of same name as the `DataContext` class. It does not use the database that I specified in the `web.config` file.

I want Country model data to be added in the `sample.mdf` file and not in the context database.

Please help... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in the connection string to use in context constructor. That way you can use any database you wish.

Answer (score 0):

A Data context class is simply just a class that maps your model classes to tables in the database. In the web config the connection string name should be the same as your context class (datacontext.cs):

```
<add name="datacontext" connectionString="[connectionstringhere]" />
```

If the connection string pointed to a SQL CE database that doesn’t exist... When you run the application, EF detects that the database didn’t exist and automatically creates it from the models set in the data context class.